# Custom waveform in hardware

Tags: clock

I need to create a custom square wave at the hardware level.

It's a 3.3 V signal at 100 kHz but the high portion of the form needs to be 9.78 MicroSeconds and the low portion needs to be 220 NanoSeconds.

I assume this is a solved problem, but my google fu has failed me thus far, as has my search for a programmable clock device with this capability.

Thank you for your help,

(Update, edited to clarify units)

Comment: What is more important? the accuracy of 100KHz or the 220ns or the ratio of the pulse to cycle time?

Comment: Do you consider an MCU a software solution?

Comment: I think there's something wrong.  A period of 9.78 milliseconds is a frequency of just over 100 Hz.  That's a far cry from 100kHz.  Did you mix up the units somewhere?

Comment: Tony, the accuracy of 100Khz is more important.  On more cafeful measurement it's actually 98.8Khz;  Winny, I tried an MCU solution but even with interrupts turned off there were weird inconsistencies in the output waveform; JRE, yes, my units were wrong, edited to clarify.  Thank you.

Comment: So is 9.8us high and 0.2us low close enough?

Comment: @JRE Sorry, my bad. Meant to edit to us but typed ms.

Comment: How did you try to use MCUs? Most MCUs that I used, allow to set up a hardware timer so waveform is generated in a hardware, no need for code to generate waveform.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way is to take a 100kHz square wave oscillator (either count down from a standard crystal oscillator or use a [custom programmed](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/si510-11.pdf) oscillator depending on accuracy and other requirements) and tack a one-shot multivibrator on the output such as [74HC123](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT123.pdf), set for your 220ns. and take the output from the /Q output.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this solution

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

So you want a 4.5MHz clock, into a counter. When the counter has value of "0000 00", you output a high. Otherwise you count for 44 more clock edges; Use a 6 bit counter (0/1/2.... 43/44) with 45 total states.